# Are my documents sufficient to enter the UK?

Tags: uk, paperwork, malaysian-citizens

I have a Malaysian passport, which allows me to visit the UK without a visa for 6 months. I left my job (Fortune 500 company) recently with the intention to travel and explore. Since my sister lives in the UK, I decided to make the UK my choice of travel.

I have visited the UK twice in the past (2-3 weeks each time) with no issue. But since this time my ticket is 6 months, I have been made aware that it raises red flags at immigration (to be honest I just stretched my return, as will likely return sooner). I have reached out to the UK embassy here in KL and the website. So I have prepared for the following:

1. Bank statement with 30K pounds (including a fixed deposit). But no continued income from the previous employment, only from my partner (see below point 5).
2. SPA of a condo I own here in KL.
3. Car ownership here in KL.
4. Home address of my sister who co-owns a house with her fiance (who is a British citizen).
5. Letter from my partner who is of European origin (has his own business), that he will be sponsoring me.
6. Full travel insurance coverage.

Is this sufficient? If this would be a problem then should I just change my ticket to something sooner? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: With 30,000 GBP available to you to last up to 6 months, you likely don't need financial sponsorship from your partner. 30,000 is about the median annual income in the UK.

Comment: @Maya What did the U.K. embassy is KL tell you?

Comment: If you turn up at a UK airport and tell the immigration officer that you're 'travelling' but you intend to stay with your sister for six months he could be forgiven for thinking that there's more to it. Six months is a long time to stay one place, so while your intentions and documentation are good, you might expect to be taken aside for a chat to verify your story. You say you'll probably stay less than six months. If that's really the case consider changing your ticket to a shorter period.

Comment: Your case may be problematic. You say you have £30,000 in your account. Was it a one time lump/large deposit into your account? If that is the case it will raise a multitude of flags and you could be denied entry for [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications). Having adequate is not enough, the clear source of the funds and it's genuineness and sustainability is of paramount importance. I was previously denied a visa for funds parking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need advice for UK landing interview (visa-free entry)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85927/need-advice-for-uk-landing-interview-visa-free-entry), and [How long can I stay in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86436/how-long-can-i-stay-in-the-uk), and possibly [Are there any documents one needs to provide at the UK Border?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78828/are-there-any-documents-one-needs-to-provide-at-the-uk-border-standard-visitor)